# How to repeat a simple command on multiple objects?

Tags: r

I have 20 unique linear models created from 1 dataset. Each one was created by:

```
mymodel1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + etc, data=mydata)
```

Now all I want to do is create a list of the output of a command on all 20 models, e.g. something like:

```
summary(mymodel[i])$adj
for i=1,2,...,20
```

It's probably obvious, but I'm not finding anything on this.

Is this the best way to act on 20 variable names that change by a positive integer?

```
for (i in 1:20) print(somefunction(eval(parse(text=paste0("model", i))))$adj)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return a vector of items in your workspace that inherit from class of 'lm":

```
    lm.names <- ls()[ sapply( ls(), function(x) 'lm' %in% class(get(x) ))]
```

This will return a list of summary items from all of them.

```
    sapply( lm.names, function(x) summary( get(x) )
```

Notice the use of `get` (twice). The `ls` function returns the names of object but neither as the objects themselves nor as true R names, but rather as a character vector. You might want to look carefully at the "Value" section of ?summary.lm, because it's a list and perhaps you only want a few items form that list?

Comment: This is definitely informative and will be useful for me in the future, but I think lukeA's solution in the comments section is what I was looking for for the moment. I had the for(i in 1:20) print(summary()) part but I didn't the understanding of how to reference the index. Thank you.